# Is "to" optional in this line?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, particles, focus-particles

Japanese: Omae o tadashi katta (to) ukeireteita.

English: I did admit that you was right.

It's correct without "to"? Omae o tadashi katta ukeireteita.

Thanks!

Comment: "ukeineteita" doesn't make sense. Isn't it ukeireta (受け入れた) or ukeireteita (受け入れていた)?

Comment: Ukeireteita, yes.

Comment: Do you mean "I admitted that you were right"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically, without the と this sentence wouldn't be correct. Without the と, this sentence would have two predicates (正｛ただ｝しかった and 受｛う｝け入｛い｝れていた), and is clearly not syntactical. A sentence should has exactly one predicate.

Answer (score 0):

> お前を正しかった**と**受け入れていた。
>   Omae o tadashi katta (to) ukeireteita.

This と (*to*) is a quotative particle, and is mandatory. Even in the most casual and hasty conversations, people do not drop the quotative particle altogether. But と can be replaced with って in casual conversations.

Comment: OPのローマ字が tadashi**i** katta（ただしいかった）になってますよね・・(タイポかも・・タイポじゃないかも・・)

Comment: how is を correct?  shouldn't it be が?

Comment: Both are fine. "to accept him as being right" vs "to admit that he was right".

Comment: It's not tadashiikatta, it's tadashikatta.

Comment: ありがとうございます、直しました～